# C# How to show the progressbar according to my percentage

Tags: c#, .net

I included a download option in my Windows application. I would like to update the progress bar result as per my calculated percentage. I calculated the percentage in one class and used `yield return` to return the percentage:

```
 int percertage = ((int)(((decimal)Offset / (decimal)FileSize) * 100));
 yield return "Percentage: " + percertage.ToString() + "%";
```

How do I assign it to my progress bar update the value according to the percentage?

Answer (score 1):

In the [progress bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) we have a function called `PerformStep()` using which we can make the progress of the progress bar increase slightly.

```
pBar1.PerformStep();
```

Comment: ya checked out this function but i am downloading 5mb files but the progress bar is finished before the download completed.....and i also used the progressBar3.Step = 1; progressBar3.Minimum = 0; progressBar3.Maximum = 450; also in that the maxim value is not fixed for every file right ....if iam downloading 10mb file thi maximum value not suit so is there any suggestion for this prob

Comment: then, assign the value of the `percentage` you calculated to the  `progressbar.value`  as suggested by deepi.

Comment: i got another prob actually i am returning this three from oneclass   yield return "Percentage : " + percertage.ToString() +"%" ; yield return percertage.ToString(); yield return SummaryText;

Comment: Now the thing is in my main class i need to get all the return values from that class so i used this code foreach (string str in objDownload.ClientDownload()){if (str.ToLower().Contains("percentage")){ lblPercentage.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblPercentage.Text = str; }); progressBar3.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar3.Value = int.Parse(str); });

Comment: i am getting error because in progressBar3.Value = int.Parse(str); this str contains three values that i am returning from another class so input string is not in correct format dono how to solve this..plz tell what i have to

Comment: what are the three values can you give an example?

Comment: thanks for your reply its working.i just assign to a static variable and called in my main function its working good....thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int percertage= ((int)(((decimal)Offset / (decimal)FileSize) * 100));
pgbrValue.Value = percertage;//it's in C#
yield return "Percentage : " + percertage.ToString() + "%";
```

Comment: i got another prob actually i am returning this three from one class  yield return "Percentage : " + percertage.ToString() +"%" ;
yield return percertage.ToString();
yield return SummaryText; Now the thing is in my mail class i need to get all the return values from that class so i used this code foreach (string str in objDownload.ClientDownload()){if (str.ToLower().Contains("percentage")){                                lblPercentage.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblPercentage.Text = str; }); progressBar3.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar3.Value = int.Parse(str); });

Comment: i am getting error because in progressBar3.Value = int.Parse(str); this str contains three values that i am returning from another class so input string is not in correct format dono how to solve this..plz tell what i have to do

Comment: take global variable and after getting percentage assign that to one of the global variable. so you can directly get that value without returning

Comment: thanks yaar its working.i just assign to a static variable and called in my main function its working good....thank u so much